# EF - For an already created entity: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'Languages'; column does not allow nulls

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I'm receiving that error when trying to insert a new item but when linking it with an already created(Language) record:

```
  var languageRepository = RepositoryFactory.CreateReadOnly<Language>();
  _defaultLanguage = languageRepository.FirstOrDefault(l => l.IsDefault);

  (...)

 newItem.Images = new List<Image>
                {
                    new Image
                    {
                          FileName = filename,
                          Language = _defaultLanguage
                    }
                };
```

In this case `_defaultLanguage` already exists in the database, then I don't know why it is trying to insert it as a new record instead of just linking to the already existent Id.

The content of _defaultLanguage:

[image]

Any idea that could help?

Comment: What type is `Language` and please publish Images keys as well as the Item keys.

Comment: you have to put more code to get the help.

Comment: your error is about the Languages table, yet your code is about the Image table. Seems like _defaultLanguage isn't what you think

Comment: I don't know what _defaultLanguage contains at this exact moment, put a break point and check it out, tell us what's in there

Comment: I added more details to help in post, please let me know your comments.

Comment: I don't see any code in your question that does an insert.

Comment: @RobertHarvey newItem is wrapping that concept in code. Or do you need to have the line newItem.Save() ?

Comment: Is `languageRepository` using different `DbContext`?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier I added the _defaultLanguage properties values.

Comment: @AlbertoMontellano, Does the problem persist when you change `CreateReadOnly` to normal extraction ?

Comment: If newItem is an object of a class that you've written written that saves a new item, then we need to see that code.  If you're just using newItem.Save(), then we need to see that code in context of the code you've already shown us.  For more info on how to do this properly, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @OrelEraki you're right! I changed that to normal extraction and it worked.

Comment: @OrelEraki Hope you can put your answer here no ? It'll help others in future.

Comment: Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: @Sampath, Thanks mate, added.

Comment: @AlbertoMontellano, Added the comment as answer.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateReadOnly` looks suspicious.

Try changing the below, to a normal extraction.

```
var languageRepository = RepositoryFactory.CreateReadOnly<Language>();
```

I believe it `Detach(Untracked)` the entries extracted.

Comment: What is " normal extraction"?

Comment: I can not guess how does he make this `RepositoryFactory` i guess it's something like `.GetRepositoryInstance<Language>()`

Comment: So why do you answer an unclear question? But how would *you* define "normal extraction"?

Comment: @GertArnold here is the feedback from the OP :`@OrelEraki you're right! I changed that to normal extraction and it worked.`.Hope he sorted out the issue.Hence I think this tip is suitable as an answer.

Comment: No it isn't. It's not at all useful to future readers. You coined this term yourself, so you must have had some idea of what you were saying, I guess.

Comment: @GertArnold, The OP is using a self made wrapper upon EntityFramework. I can only guess how he decided to call the actual method that Query his SQL Repository. I don't think that getting his actual method name for repository query (probably backed with Dictionary) will help future readers, but rather mentioning that EntityFramework extraction is needed.